# Eloquent get row with most attached relationships

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

i have a 'projects' table and a 'users' table.
users are able to like projects. this is a many  to many relationship using a pivot table.

i would like to get the project with the most likes connected to it. 
is there a simple way to achieve this using eloquent?

The only way i can think of right now is by building to seperate queries, which i like to avoid.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join your pivot table and count the results like

```
$projects = Project::join('project_likes as pl', 'pl.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
->groupBy('projects.id')
->orderBy('count','desc')
->get(['projects.*', DB::raw('COUNT(pl.project_id) as count')]);
```

I think that should work. If not, let me know, I will check it and edit my answer. Of course if you want you can add `->limit(1)` to get only one result. Or use `first` instead of `get` with the same parameters.